# Executing a function/script outside of .html file?

Tags: javascript, html, web, calc

I would like to make a simple web calculator to allow some field technicians to enter numerical data into it and calculate a result. The problem is that the page will be hosted publicly, though our calculations are something we'd like hidden from outside interests. Is there a way to hide the formula or call an outside script so we don't expose our methods to people who may want to inspect the .html file?

I have experience writing basic HTML but am far from a web developer. Please give links or detailed instructions if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the calculations will be done in the browser, then the code to do the calculations must be sent to the browser.  If the browser can figure it out, so can a person.

If you are *really* serious about hiding your algorithm, you should probably create a service that runs on a server that you control.  The web page would collect the inputs, send them to the server and respond with the outputs from the calculation.

EDIT:
Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your calculation algorithms *executed* on the client, you're out of luck.  Anything you send to the browser must be considered "open".  The only method of hiding anything is obfuscation, and that is usually easily undone.

If hiding your algorithms is more important you will need to have a server that performs the operations and exposes an API for the client to access.  (EG: Client says "hey server, calculate `X` for me" the server performs the algorithm with `X` and sends back the answer)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with Javascript inside of a html file. You can  [minify](http://jscompress.com/) or [obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscateprotect-javascript) which can help a bit. This can make the Javascript harder to read or understand but it's relying on security through obscurity, in other words, if someone is determined enough they can figure out what's going on.

The best way to solve this is to set up a server that does the calculations. A client webpage can send a request to the server and return the results, while preventing people from seeing how it's done. This is how Google keeps it's search function private despite returning the results.